# Creating a new column in a dataframe based on matches with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

Dataframe 1:

```
ID  MONTH
1   2010-01
1   2010-03
1   2010-04
2   2010-01
3   2010-01
3   2010-02
```

Dataframe 2:

```
ID  MONTH
1   2010-01
3   2010-02
```

Is there a way to create a new column in Dataframe 1 based on row matches on both the ID and Month column in dataframe2?

So that the end result would look like:

```
  ID    MONTH Match
0  1  2010-01     Y
1  1  2010-03     N
2  1  2010-04     N
3  2  2010-01     N
4  3  2010-01     N
5  3  2010-02     Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with `merge` + `indicator`, return `both` will be `Yes`, `left_only` will be `No`

```
s=df1.merge(df2,indicator=True,how='left')
s['Match']=s.pop('_merge').map({'both':'Y','left_only':'N'})
s
Out[18]: 
   ID    MONTH Match
0   1  2010-01     Y
1   1  2010-03     N
2   1  2010-04     N
3   2  2010-01     N
4   3  2010-01     N
5   3  2010-02     Y
```

Comment: @MalikM yw :-) happy coding ~